# how to center link image in div

Tags: html, css

Could you please how to center vertially image link in div of item-image?
This is fixed size div and I want images of smaller height are vertially aligned.

This doesn't work for some reason.

```
.item-image {
    height: 256px;
    width: 256px;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 256px;
}

.item-image a {
    display: block;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;

}
```

I wonder why it didn't work.

I also tried:

1. .item-image a {
       vertical-align: middle;
       display: table-cell;
       height: 100%; }

But it doesn't work too.

```
 <div class="item">
        <div class="item-image">
           <a href="/folder/download?target=%2Fimages1%2Fpng%2Fimage_48.png">
             <img src="/.tmb/l1_aW1hZ2VzMS9wbmcvaW1hZ2VfNDgucG5n.png" alt=""/>
           </a>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this to your classes

```
.item-image {
    position: relative;
}

.item-image a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: It aligns veritally image, but image is not aligned horintalliy any more.

Comment: Horizantal align doesn't work for some reason even with left: 50%;

Comment: I also added translateX(-50%);

Comment: thats just cause there is no actual image

Answer (score 1):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ktuCE/2/)**

**css**

```
.item-image{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
  border:1px solid red;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.item-image a {
    display: inline-block;
       border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Image can be the same size as item-image div.

Comment: @oleg please remove width height .item-image a

Answer (score 0):

Add `height` in pixels in your CSS `.item-image a`

`.item-image a{vertical-align: middle; 
               display: table-cell; 
               height: 256px;}`

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/AvL9Y/20/)

Comment: In need center .tem-image in parent div as well.

Answer (score 0):

I did like this

```
img{width:50px; height:50px;position:relative; left:50%; margin-left:-25px}
.item-image:after{ content:""; display: inline-block;height: 100%;vertical-align: middle;}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nPJQC/)**

**Here Another Option**

Using this CSS

```
.item-image img {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;margin:auto;

}
```

Here the **[Demo New](http://jsfiddle.net/6y5SY/2/)**

Comment: Image should work even if it has the same size as .item-image.